# StAX - reading base64 string from xml into db

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, sax, stax

I'm using StAX  to read my file, which has some Base64 data in it, and saving it into the db using Hibernate.

XML:

```
<root>
  <base64>lololencoded12</base64>
  <base64>encodedlolos32</base64>
  ...............................
</root>
```

Code to read and save:

```
xmlif = (XMLInputFactory2) XMLInputFactory2.newInstance();
xmlif.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.IS_REPLACING_ENTITY_REFERENCES, Boolean.FALSE);
xmlif.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.IS_SUPPORTING_EXTERNAL_ENTITIES, Boolean.FALSE);
xmlif.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.IS_COALESCING, Boolean.FALSE); 
xmlif.configureForLowMemUsage();

List<Entity> entities = new ArrayList();
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
XMLStreamReader2 xmlr = (XMLStreamReader2) xmlif.createXMLStreamReader(filename, fis);
int eventType = xmlr.getEventType();
String curElement = "";
while (xmlr.hasNext()) {
     eventType = xmlr.next();
     switch (eventType) {
         case XMLEvent.START_ELEMENT:
             curElement=xmlr.getName().toString();
             if ("base64".equals(curElement)) {
                 Entity entity = new Entity();
                 entity.setBase64(xmlr.getElementText().getBytes());
                 session.save(entity);
                 session.flush();
             }
             break;
     }
 }
 iterator itr = entities.iterator();
 while (itr.hasNext()) {
     Entity e = (Entity)itr.next();                    
     session.saveOrUpdate(e);
 }
```

This approach gobbles memory in amount that is 6-9 times size of my xml. How can i improve this?

**EDIT**

If i comment out entity.setBase64() everything is fine. When saving byte[] to db memory usage goes bonkers. Why?

**EDIT**
Entity getters and setters:

```
    //for me
    public byte[] getBase64() {
        return base64;
    }

    public void setBase64(byte[] base64) {
        this.base64= base64;
    }


    //for hibernate
    public Blob getBase64Blob() {
        if (this.base64!=null) {
            LobCreator lobok =Hibernate.getLobCreator(MainFrame.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession());
            return lobok.createBlob(base64);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void setBase64Blob(Blob dataBlob) {
        if (dataBlob!=null) {
            this.base64= toByteArray(dataBlob);
        }
    }   

    //utilities methods from blob to byte array 
    private byte[] toByteArray(Blob fromBlob) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try {
            return toByteArrayImpl(fromBlob, baos);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } finally {
            if (baos != null) {
                try {
                    baos.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private byte[] toByteArrayImpl(Blob fromBlob, ByteArrayOutputStream baos)
            throws SQLException, IOException {
        byte[] buf = new byte[4000];
        InputStream is = fromBlob.getBinaryStream();
        try {
            for (;;) {
                int dataSize = is.read(buf);
                if (dataSize == -1)
                    break;
                baos.write(buf, 0, dataSize);
            }
        } finally {
            if (is != null) {
                try {
                    is.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                }
            }
        }
        return baos.toByteArray();
    }
```

**EDIT**
xmlr.getElementText().getBytes() causes a lot of memory usage for some reason.

Comment: Did you profile this code for memory consumption? Where does the memory go?

Comment: I can see memory usage spikes 6 times size of a actual xml.

Comment: i can see a lot of char[] and byte[] allocated

Comment: replace `entities.add(entity);` with `session.saveOrUpdate(e);`

Comment: Q: what representation of the binary base64 encoded blobs do you need stored in the db? Just the encoded text left in base64 or does that call to setBase64 actually decode the base64 text back to binary data that is stored as a blob in your db? That detail may help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How often are you flushing out your entities?

I think you're building too many entities and not flushing your session frequently enough which results in all those objects being created to be kept in the current session.

May want to check that.

**Edit**

The comments below indicated that the submitter wanted a way to insert binary blob data directly in to the database.

Instead of doing this with hibernate, this can be achieved with just JDBC.

```
java.sql.Connection conn = ...
java.sql.PreparedStatement pstmt= conn.prepareStatement("insert into ENTITY_TABLE (BASE64) VALUES (?)");
InputStream is= ... // byte data
pstmt.setBinaryStream(1, is);
int numUpdated= pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

Now be advised, this is REAL rough and tumble.  This is making the assumption that the ENTITY_TABLE is using a database generated identifier for the row and that columns other than BASE64 are allowed to have nulls or have reasonable defaults.  The executeUpdate will run the insert statement taking the value of *is* as the value of the blob data.

I hope this gets you closer to your solution.

Comment: I'm testing with xml ~11mb in size with 2 entities. Memory goes 6x of that size :(

Comment: Why do you have coalescing turned off? I'm wondering if you're getting stacks of events for your base64 data. I'm grabbing at straws here though

Comment: Turned on - nothing changes :(

Comment: how large is the base64 string? more to the point, how large is the base64 string and how large is the binary after decoding?

Comment: Well here's what I'm thinking and I'm hoping other SO'ers might be able to back me up on this. When you read the XML you get 11m represented in memory, you request the bytes, possibly another 11m of byte array now allocated, that would be a double, there may be more beyond that.  Try running up visualvm to (included in jdk 6 & higher I think) to see where you're heating up.

Comment: is it possible that hibernate logs values of blobs being saved? In profiler i see like 100 mb of byte[] allocated.

Comment: I don't recall specifically where in visualvm where it indicates memory allocations ... I would also check to make sure that hibernate is not caching entities at this time ... It looks like you want to just ram this stuff in the database more than anything else at the moment.

Comment: Is its even possible to disable cache? If only it was possible to take inputstream from xml and stream it in db somehow

Comment: There is ... but you'll have to handle identification of your records either through an identity or auto-increment column.  See body of answer for edit (coming shortly)